# Struggle to regain lost passion in physics

Tags: phd, advisor, productivity, motivation

I am a PhD student currently in my second to last year. Last year something weird happened, my supervisor forced me into projects in which I was not interested. He forced me into collaborations which I didn't want. Actually, I had already written some papers in collaboration and was trying to work independently on my own ideas. But he didn't pay a lot of attention to my ideas and calculations and asked me to jump on projects which he felt could result in a paper really fast. I did it but it broke my spirit. Having to work on things I had no interest in made me lose my motivation.

I came into physics from another field. I could have gotten a wonderful job but I left it all for physics because I love it. But after being forced to work on things that didn't interest me multiple times and not letting me do my own stuff and not paying attention to them, I lost all interest in the field. Everything felt like a waste of time. Actually I always had this idea in my mind that PhD is the time when you are supposed to learn to become an independent researcher and this situation made me feel that it was a waste of time. Also, my supervisor is obsessed with the number of papers, which resulted in average papers that could have been far better if he wasn't so hasty. I was ready to risk spending a long time on projects but he wasn't. Afterall, how can you expect to publish good results if you do not risk losing time on dead end directions? Anyway, since then I have been struggling to regain my passion and it has been a year now. I am finally allowed to do my own things but it feels useless now since I lost my drive so badly that I am finding it hard to get back on track.

Therefore, my questions to academics here: can you provide some suggestions/methods/ways to regain my lost passion since right now is the crucial time in my PhD and I feel I am wasting time because of my disrupted mindset?

Comment: Take a break. Change supervisor. Physics is a great topic, but the wrong supervisor can mess it up for you.

Answer (score 6):

I won't say that "passion" is useless, but it is not a switch you can turn on and off. Nor is this a bad thing. I am somewhat older, and I have felt a passion for pure mathematics, but this was a feeling that came and went. I would say this is the normal order of things. At first when you get into a new subject (either physics as a whole or a subdiscipline, or sub-subdiscipline) you feel excited, but it wears off.  Familiarity breeds contempt, and thorough mastery of a subject will lead inevitably to a kind of jadedness. I can feel a kind of spark when I explain something that I once found exciting to someone for whom it is unfamiliar. But this is an interpersonal thing, and I actually always feel I must warn them not to fall in love with intellectual constructs too soon.

In any case, passion will not sustain you in the long run. It is true for marriages, and it is also true for academic pursuits.

Answer (score 3):

##### Good supervisory practice should not kill the student's passion for the subject

*If you'll indulge me, I'm going to give an "answer" here that is actually directed to supervisors and is tangential to your question.  This is important to add because your question raises some important issues about good supervisory practice.  My answer won't necessarily solve your immediate problem (though it might help you have a productive conversation with supervisors), but hopefully it might diminish the prospect of it occurring to others.*

---

When supervising a PhD student, there is sometimes a trade-off between two desirable goals you want to help the student achieve: (1) establishing a publication record that will lead to entry-level career prospects in research; and (2) allowing the student freedom to explore ideas of interest to them to develop their passion for the subject.  Established academics are cognisant of the reality of "publish or perish" and we know that the competition for research positions in academia and elsewhere is fierce (and there is a huge overproduction of PhD graduates in the market).  Therefore, many well-meaning supervisors focus heavily on (1) at the expense of (2), knowing that they may be short-changing their PhD students if they don't push them hard enough to produce publications and help them gain entry-level academic positions after graduation.

This approach is okay if you are dealing with a student who is committed and disciplined and whose interest in the subject is solidified, particularly if the student's goal is to land an academic research position after graduation.  However, it is counter-productive to use this approach if doing so destroys the passion/interest of a student who could otherwise have been able to learn and practice the subject in some capacity.  Ideally, the trade-off between (1) and (2) should be formed based on explicit discussion between the student and supervisor about the career goals of the student, what they hope to get out of their PhD program, the realities of the academic market and broader research profession, and any other relevant issues.  Supervisors should teach their students the realities of what academic research looks like and how to go about getting a position in the field, but they should *let the student make an informed decision* about what they actually want in their life after graduation and what they want to get out of their candidature.  My view is that it is even good practice to explicitly tell the student about this trade-off, and that your supervisory approach will involve trying to deal with this trade-off, and that your approach can be varied if the student thinks there is too much emphasis on one end.

Some would argue that "testing" the passion of the student through heavy emphasis on (1) at the expense of (2) is actually a desirable thing, since it acts as a filtering mechanism during the candidature --- any student who is insufficiently happy with the harsher realities of professional research and the "publish or perish" culture is dissuaded from continuing in the field and directed towards some non-PhD activity.  This view assumes that the only value in a PhD is to secure and practice a professional academic position, which I reject.  There are students who will do their PhD and decide that they don't wish to practice in academia or any other "publish or perish" field.  For these students, a smaller number of papers in areas of passion for them is far more valuable than a larger suite of paper to pad out a CV for a job application in academia (and again, the *student* should make an informed decision on this).

Comment: "I could have gotten a wonderful job" - so excellent points made. +1

Comment: You list two goals.  In my experience, there is a third one which is very important to many (misguided?) supervisors and universities:  Ensuring the student completes their PhD, and does so on the prescribed schedule.  If thier student is at risk of failing, those supervisors tell them exactly what to do and they pick something easy, not something good for the student's career.

Comment: Getting more money to pay the your students with is also an important goal for supervisors.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I agree with you that the goal of the supervisor is to ensure that the student passes. Maybe, indeed, the student is in danger to fail, but given that they have multiple papers, I did not assume that this was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

To recover lost passion in a subject, I cannot recommend anything more highly than the ["plate story"](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/kilcup.1/262/feynman.html) from the physicist Richard Feynman.  (I also highly recommend the book this comes from; it is wonderful!)  Feynman talks of having lost his passion for his subject for the exact same reason as you --- because he was focusing on "important" problems instead of playing with the things he wanted.  He decides to go back to playing with problems of interest to him with no concern for their importance and it brings back his passion.

Comment: In principle, yes. But this is not a burn-out due to overinvestment. This is simply a supervisor who changed goalposts. Spinning plate example does not work here - the supervisor has grabbed the plate out of the air and told the student to sit down and eat properly, so to say.

Comment: But according to OP, "finally I am being allowed to do my own things", so it appears that the previous imposition is now gone.

Comment: Maybe the supervisor gave up on them. But the damage is done.

Answer (score 0):

Just take some time to rest from physics. It's burnout. More walking on open air, especially on sunny days, take vitamin D and good sleep. And desire to work magically will return sooner or later (can take half year though)

Answer (score -8):

Passion is not useful in physics.  Hard work is.

If you are not enjoying your work, you should not be a PhD student.  Find a job you would like better, and if you cannot do that, find one that at least pays more, so you can use the money for something you like.

You say your mindset is "disrupted" but it is more likely you just learned what a PhD is really like.

Comment: I think that your advice - which I usually appreciate - is off here. The supervisor seems not to be suitable fit to OP. OP does not appear to be lazy, but rather interested taking things further and a more deliberate and thought-through pace. We cannot know if OP really has good ideas, but it is clear that the supervisor does not even consider them and does not really give feedback on them. Also, if OP has the right judgement, the supervisor prefers a shallow but fast style. In short, I think the advice does not respond to the question as it has been asked. Do you want to amend your response?

Comment: @CaptainEmacs No.  I think your misunderstanding is that you think this is the supervisor's style.  It is more likely that the supervisor's behavior reflects the choices of the source of funding.  The asker cannot do anything about that.  The last sentence answers the question:  The passion is not coming back.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Thank you for elaborating my situation. I also feel that the answer does not address what I am asking. I have been a very diligent student all my life. I worked really really hard on my previous projects. It's just the way I was forced into things which I wasnt interested in and also was forced into a type of research I thought was very superficial and shallow that I lost my interest. I don't have an issue with hardwork. And I disagree with the statement that "passion is not useful in phy". I think both are very useful and my case is a living example of this.

Comment: I lost all passion which made me lose all drive to work hard.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist "Reflects the choices of the source of funding" - there are no indications of the source of funding or such constraints in the question. Who says it's not just institution money? "The passion is not coming back.": of course not. As long OP is in that situation, the fun in research has been squeezed out of them. I have taken on students who left a supervision relation because it was unsuitable. It is very clear that passion, drive and hard work come back when in the right circumstances. Your response does not answer the question as asked and makes unwarranted assumptions. -1

Comment: @CaptainEmacs That is based on my experience with funding processes, including institutional money processes.  It is not based on the question.

Comment: Of course the asker can find a better supervisor, substantially delaying the completion of their PhD.  That will not change the pressure to publish many papers, or the fact that being a PhD student is rather different from their past experiences.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Ok, this does not match my experience - supervisors have considerable leeway, unless they hired the student for a very specific narrow field. If that's the case, that needs to be discussed beforehand when accepting the student. And it's the supervisor, with their considerably larger experience, that should have made expectations clear (and elicit student expectations) in the student interview. I find the response lets supervisors get off the hook a bit too easily. We all have publication pressure, but some top groups  insist on spending more time on better papers.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I just noticed one specific sentence which says it all, sorry that I didn't see it that clearly before, and made the point earlier, would have saved us some discourse: "my supervisor forced me into projects I was not interested in" - this is classic "bait and switch". Nonetheless, thank you for the discussion.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I read that as "my supervisor forced me into projects that please the funding source."  If you do not please the funding source, that will always happen.  Physics PhD students do not get free choice of research subject.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist "Funding source" is nowhere in the question, and I do not remember having read it (i.e. I do not think it was edited out). So, it is patently not OP's case as described and the scene sounds very much like a bait and switch. Frankly, if research is expected to be such a joyless matter, there is far more money to be made at equally joyless jobs in industry. The candidate specifically chose the PhD because they wanted to do something else. I would think differently if I thought the OP was coasting around different topics without focus, but that does not seem to be the issue.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist "Physics PhD students do not get free choice of research subject" Really? Maybe not anymore, but then things changed drastically since my times. But OP already *was* in their PhD. Supervisor changed the rules in the 2nd year. OP has written some papers, so it's not like they were not doing anything and supervisor felt they had to intervene.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs "in the 2nd year." That is not what the question says.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist You are right. It says "second to last year". Which makes my point stronger, as this is probably even later into the PhD work.

Comment: That is also not when the question says the projects changed.  I do not believe you know the supervisor's reasoning.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist "...my supervisor forced me into projects in which I was not interested. He forced me into collaborations which I didn't want" - sorry, but you work exceedingly hard to somehow construct a justification for the supervisor. Of course OP might hide relevant information from us, but I think it is a matter of courtesy and respect to assume that OPs are essentially giving us a fair picture of the situation. Even if the supervisor suddenly discovers that they cannot fund the student anymore, the very least to be expected is that they explain the situation to the student.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs My interpretation is not a justification.  It's more the opposite.  Nor do I suggest the question is misleading in any way.  I suggest you are wrong to discount funding.  Funding is very influential in the majority of decisions made in physics.  I suggest you are wrong to attribute poor/harmful actions to the nature of the supervisor; in general people make poor choices due to external factors rather than their nature.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist There is no indication that anything like that happened. The projects may have pre-existed, but OP was forced into them only later. I do not understand how you construct a case in favour of the supervisor based on the question. I can't believe you as a physicist  would accept any study where data would be forced into a obviously preconceived model like that. I do not claim to know the supervisor's reasoning, but you claim you know. However, to make it fit, you have to bend OPs story with assumptions not supported by the question. Your case has been so far unconvincing.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Ok, now I finally see where you are coming from, but this means one of two things: the supervisor is very bad at communicating; at managing; or is just in panic mode (i.e. bad at both). Still, the answer does not help. The "hard work" story is just not solving the OP's problem. There is no point for someone forgoing a well-paying career to do soul-destroying work to satisfy some grant they had no interesting in working for in the first place. And frankly, if a grant does not try answer a good scientific question, what a waste of money, to boot.

Comment: Finally "what a PhD is really like" - I fundamentally disagree. A PhD should be one of the most deeply fun times in a researcher's career; if it's not, one does something wrong. Sure, there will be frustrating stretches, this is in the nature of things. But it should be meaningful, or why do it at all?

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I mostly agree with your last two posts.  The reality I have observed is that nearly all PhD students get a worse deal than I got when I was a PhD student.  Less freedom, less pay, etc.